# ASP.Net MVC Chart Control - Position AxisY Points

Tags: asp.net

I have a chart control and would like to position the columns on the YAxis so that they begin on the left of the chart.

Does anyone know how to control the position of the YAxis?

Comment: So you are saying you want to rotate a bar chart so it goes left-to-right instead of bottom-to-top?

Comment: @jadamel27 No I wanted to move the columns in the bar chart to the left. Right now they are on the cross hairs.